# Why does VC++ 2010 allow this to compile?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
std::vector<const int> vci;
vci.push_back(1);
vci[0] = 2;
```

With the element type being `const int`, shouldn't the assignment statement be assigning to a `const int&`?  This does not compile with LLVM 3.0.  Why does VC++ allow it?

Comment: You apparently do not understand what the "undefined" word in "undefined behavior" means.

Comment: flattery will get you everywhere -- i could have worded that a little better.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to be offensive, but quite often undefined behavior is mistaken for a runtime crash or a compile error guarantee. Nothing could be farther from the truth. C++ is full of places in which something that could seem reasonable is indeed forbidden but in which the compiler is not in charge for checking. Undefined behavior means just don't do that... means the compiler writers are free to assume a programmer won't do that. The worst thing that can happen is indeed just "nothing" ... or to say it better nothing until the demo or deploy day.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While it is Undefined Behavior and basically *anything* can happen including what you are seeing, I have tracked this to what seems to be an incompatibility of the library with the standard. In particular the standard allocator defined in the VS2010 library does not conform with the standard.

The standard dictates that `std::vector<T,Allocator>::value_type` is a typedef to `Allocator::value_type`. Now the default allocator (if none is provided) is `std::allocator<T>` for which `value_type`, according to *Table 28* must be *Identical to T*. Now the implementation of the standard allocator in VS2010 drops the `const` qualifier from the type argument, so `std::allocator<const T>::value_type` is `T`, and not `const T`.

It is important to note that the compiler is not non-conformant for accepting the code that you provided per-se, since it is Undefined Behavior and the compiler is free to do as it pleases. But on the other hand, there is a non-conformity in the `std::allocator` implementation.

<strike>You have already answered the question yourself: It is *Undefined Behavior*. The compiler does not need to provide a diagnostic, and the result of the operation can be anything. It is a case of quality of implementation to detect that the type is not assignable and provide a meaningful error message (or not)</strike>

Comment: However, one would *expect* that in any practical implementation of `std::vector`, there would be somewhere attempting to make an assignment, which should lead to a flat-out compiler error.  The fact that this doesn't happen makes it interesting; what tricks is the MSVC implementation pulling?

Comment: how is it possible that this is a QoI issue?  how is it possible for this to be implemented *without* an assignment to `const`?  it seems like UB to use a non-assignable UDT, but using a `const` type flat out violates language rules, no?

Comment: @Oli: My guess is that they discard the *const volatile* qualifiers from the type.

Comment: and the standard permits discarding the CV qualifiers?

Comment: @Tabber33: If the difference is only perceivable in code that is already undefined behavior, then it does not affect the conformity of the code with the standard and it becomes QoI.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: ok that makes sense i guess.  this must be special-case logic to drop the CV for STL container template parameter?  it doesn't do it for UDTs.  why on earth would they do this?

Comment: @Tabber33: I don't think this is just a case of intentionally dropping it for `vector`, but rather a side effect of how the vector is implemented.

Comment: Thank you Mr Lister and Oli Charlesworth. You piqued my curiosity a bit too much >.>

Comment: @Tabber33: After chasing the code and the standard, only `const` is dropped, and it happens in `std::allocator`, which makes that implementation of the allocator non-conforming with Table 28 in the standard (that requires `value_type` to be *identical to T*). It seems that it is actually non-conforming, not because `const` is dropped, but because it is dropped in `std::allocator`)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: how exactly is the `const` "dropped?"  is there a `const_cast` in there somewhere?

Comment: @Tabber33: `const_cast` drops constness from an object, not from a type. For types it is about the simplest metaprogramming you can do with types: `template <typename T> struct remove_const { typedef T type; }; template <typename T> struct remove_const<T const> { typedef T type; };` (well in this case this is a base of the allocator and `type` is actually `value_type`, but the approach is the same.